# How to prove that $x^9-9x^7+27x^5-30x^3+9x-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

The problem says:
Given the irreducible polynomial $x^3-3x-1$ with root $2\cos(\pi/9)$, prove that $2\cos(\pi/27)$ is a root of a monic irreducible polynomial of degree 9 over $\mathbb{Q}$, and hence $[\mathbb{Q}(2\cos(\pi/27)):\mathbb{Q}]=9.$

To solve it, I substituted the equality $2\cos(\pi/9)=8\cos^3(\pi/27)-6\cos(\pi/27)$ on the equation $x^3-3x-1=0$ to obtain that $2\cos(\pi/27)$ is a root of the monic polynomial $x^9-9x^7+27x^5-30x^3+9x-1$. But now, how I prove that $x^9-9x^7+27x^5-30x^3+9x-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Do you know about degree of field extensions and stuff like that?

Comment: Yes, I know about degree of field extensions.

Comment: then you can try to show that the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(cos(\pi /27))$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $9$ by the way you already know that $\mathbb{Q}(cos(\pi /27))$ over $\mathbb{Q}(cos(\pi /9))$ is $3$ and $\mathbb{Q}(cos(\pi / 9))$ over $\mathbb{Q} $ is $3$

Comment: Why $\mathbb{Q}(2cos(\pi /27))$ over $\mathbb{Q}(2cos(\pi /9))$ is 3?

Comment: I am sorry I thought it was easy but now I am finding it idfficult

Comment: I think, the easy way is proving the irreducibility of the polynomial. Solving that we have that $[\mathbb{Q}(2\cos(\pi/27)):\mathbb{Q}]=9$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The computation is a little horrendous ([I used WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2B1%29%5E9-9%28x%2B1%29%5E7%2B27%28x%2B1%29%5E5-30%28x%2B1%29%5E3%2B9%28x%2B1%29-1)), but you can show that
$$(x+1)^9-9(x+1)^7+27(x+1)^5-30(x+1)^3+9(x+1)-1$$
expands to be
$$x^9+9 x^8+27 x^7+21 x^6-36 x^5-54 x^4+9 x^3+27 x^2-3$$
which is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion with $p=3$, which means that
$$x^9-9x^7+27x^5-30x^3+9x-1$$
is also irreducible.

**EDIT:**

As Michalis points out, we can avoid the computation just by considering the polynomial modulo $3$, and then considering the constant coefficient modulo $9$. Since we have coefficients which are multiples of $3$, $P(x+1)\pmod{3}$ becomes
$$(x+1)^9-1\pmod3\equiv x^9+1-1\pmod3\equiv x^9\pmod3$$ 
Hence all the coefficients of the expanded polynomial are divisible by $3$ except for the first. Now we consider the constant coefficient modulo $9$: This is just
$$1-9+27-30+9-1\pmod9=1-0+0-3+0-1\pmod9\equiv-3\pmod9$$
So $9$ doesn't divide the final coefficient, and we have satisfied all the conditions necessary to use Eisenstein's criterion as above.

Comment: To avoid the horrendous calculation you can just look at $P(X)$ mod $3$. Then it's just $\overline{P}(X)=X^9-1$ and clearly $\overline{P}(X+1)=X^9$, so all coefficients of $P(X+1)$ are divisible by $3$. The only thing left to check is that $9$ doesn't divide the constant coefficient.

Comment: @Michalis Thanks for the observation. That made it much easier.

Comment: I continue asking if there anyway to deduce that the polynomial is irreducible based on the information that $x^3-3x-1$ is irreducible and proving that my substitution on that polynomial doesn't alter that, so the new generated polynomial maintain the property of irreducibility...